# How to get pixel value from an image?

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

Are there any ways to get the pixel values from an image on particular location?

I'm using NativeScript to develop an Android application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work in NativeScript, but in Javascript you could use `.getImageData` to get individual RGBA values